# Is there a way to create config file(to specify compiler options) for absolute paths in svelte like we can have jsconfig.json for javascript projects

Tags: javascript, svelte

## demo jsconfig.json file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src"
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

The svelte components will have .svelte extension. So, is there a way to specify compiler options for Svelte just like this?

Answer (score 0):

A demo of `svelte.config.js` file with `svelte-preprocess`:

https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess#with-svelte-vs-code

The list of Svelte compile time options:

https://svelte.dev/docs#Compile_time

I hope this will help you